# Show Open TabItem Names in a List View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I'm trying to display a list of open tab names in a listview or listbox (recommendations?).

Been going through the different type of binding options and I'm able to bind to a single tab name but it displays vertical instead of horizontal. Here is my XAML:

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Left"
          Height="352"
          Name="listView1"
          Width="132"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=RulesTab, Path=Name}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
          DataContext="{Binding}">
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated as I'd like to be able to see a list of all the tabs open and then double click on one to bring the tab into focus. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand what your main problem is, do you just need a fix for the items being listed vertically instead of horizontally?

Comment: I guess there's multiple problems sorry :) Mainly, how do I get it to list all the tabitem names in the tabcontrol? Right now I am able to only get it to display a single tabitem header (RuleTab above in my code is a single tab). I've tried setting the binding to the tabcontrol name and then choosing name, header and tabindex...still nothing displays in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a `TabControl` and a `ListBox` showing the names of the `TabItems` that are in it:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl Grid.Column="0" Name="tabControl1">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1"/>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2"/>
        <TabItem Header="Tab3"/>
        <TabItem Header="Tab4"/>
    </TabControl>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=tabControl1}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_DoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

and here's the code behind:

```
private void ListBoxItem_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
{
    var tabItem = (TabItem)((ListBoxItem)sender).Content;
    tabControl1.SelectedItem = tabItem;
}
```

**Edited** to add double-click behavior.

Comment: thanks this works! although, 3 responses all 3 did the trick. i don't know how to give all 3 credit :)

Comment: excellent, thanks very much for adding the double-click behavior this is working great!

Answer (score 1):

Simplified example how to enumerate the tabs in a tab control with a listview:

```
<TabControl Name="MyTabControl">
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>

<ListView  DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=Items}" 
           DataContext="{Binding}">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unsure as to what exactly you want, anyway, this can be adjusted if needed.
First of all if you bind to a specific item you will always have one item, you need to set `ItemsSource` to a collection.
Assuming you want to have the names or headers of all the tabs in your list you can set the tab control's `Items` as the `ItemsSource` and then apply a `ItemTemplate`, some example code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=TabControlSrc, Path=Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If you do not use the `ItemTemplate` you'll get an error because the same item can only be a visual child of one parent.
Frankly this seems a bit pointless since it just reiterates your tabs, did i misunderstand something? If so please clarify further.

Edit: Oh lol, three almost identical answers...